# Add cell address to an array when cell value = 0 VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a range of cells that a for loop goes over. If there is a cell with a 0 in it, change to some number and save cell address to an array?

I'm not sure how many cells will have 0 to begin with.

Below is pseudo code for how I want it to work

```
For i = 1 to 9
     For j = 1 to 9
         if cell.value = 0 then
            cell.value = x
            '''Add cell.address to array'''
         End if
     next j
next i
```

Edit:
Thanks for all your guys' help. Now that I can reference add the address to an array, is there a way to return to the address as necessary?
I want to be able to reference the last cell I modified as something Like this as seen within the three block quote marks:

```
For i = 1 to 9
         For j = 1 to 9
             if cell.value = 0 then
                cell.value = x
                nums(n) = cell.adress
              n = n+1
             Elseif cell.value = y
           """Return back to the last cell added to the array, and put x+1"""
             End if
         next j
 next i
```

If I need to open another question I can.

Comment: You mean adding zeros to a 2-dimensional array or a 1-dimensional array?

Comment: I think I had a couple of bugs due to reusing variable i. Please, checkout corrected code.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim ranges(81) ' Enough to hold 9x9 ranges
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
k = 1
For i = 1 to 9
     For j = 1 to 9
         If cell.value = 0 then
            cell.value = x
            Set ranges(k) = cell
            k = k + 1
         ElseIf k>1 Then
            Set ranges(k-1).Value = x+1
         End if
     next j
next i
```

Comment: You have `i = i + 1` within the For ... Next loop also using i. Will this not affect the working of the loop?

Comment: Hey Tarik, this looks good but quick question, how can i then reference a specific cell with the array I have created such that I can return to it and modify? For example: If I I put an if statement that if the current cell value = 6, I need to go back to the last cell I modified from 0. I will edit the code to show.

Comment: See modified solution that stores ranges instead of addresses and should do the job.

Comment: Side note: think you are aware that in a declaration like `Dim i, j, k as Integer` only `k` gets the `Integer` data type, `i` and `j` will be`Variants` if not declared expressly @Tarik

Comment: You are welcome. - Similarly as in OP: `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k as Integer`; I'd prefer even `As Long`, especially for higher counters and due to the internal VBA reversion to `Long` @Tarik

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function. It returns both the count and the string of addresses. One of the arguments it takes is the value with which found zeroes are to be replaced.

```
Private Sub Test_CountSeroes()
    Dim Addresses() As String
    MsgBox CountZeroes("Replaced", Addresses)
    Debug.Print Join(Addresses, ",")
End Sub

Function CountZeroes(ByVal x As Variant, _
                     Fun() As String) As Long

    Const CountRange    As String = "B2:H13"    ' change to suit
    
    Dim Rng             As Range                ' = CountRange
    Dim Cell            As Range                ' loop counter: cells
    Dim i               As Long                 ' index of Fun()
    
    Set Rng = Range(CountRange)
    ReDim Fun(1 To Rng.Count)
    For Each Cell In Rng
        With Cell
            If .Value = 0 Then
                .Value = x
                i = i + 1
                Fun(i) = .Address(0, 0)
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    If i Then ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To i)
    CountZeroes = i
End Function
```